# jquery: use (“parent > child”) with variables

Tags: jquery

For example I have a `<div class="first">` containig other `<div>` 's and selected first one and pushed him into variable

```
variable = $('div.first')
```

And now I want something like this

```
$(variable + " > div")
```

I know, it seems stupid but what if I had an array containig table rows and I need to access columns inside a specific row:

```
var tableRows = $('table > tbody > tr');
var tableBodyCols = $(tableRows[i]+'> td'); // Doesn't work :(
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
var tableBodyCols = tableRows.children('td');
```

Or a context selector:

```
var tableBodyCols = $('> td', tableRows);
```

Both are equivalent but the former is easier to read imho.

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/punkw/) demonstrating both.

---

And to iterate over all sets of children of [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) table row:

```
tableRows.each(function() {
    var tableBodyCols = $(this).children('td');
    //...
});
```

But if you really prefer a `for` loop or you need to get a specific row's columns, then [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is your friend.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    var tableBodyCols = tableRows.eq(i).children('td');
    //...
}
```

Here's the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/punkw/1/).

Comment: the former is much more efficient too

Comment: @Alnitak Yes nicely noted, it doesn't create a new jQuery object from scratch too. `=]`

Comment: My english is bad, and I was thinking that `children()` selector selects only first child (I thought "children" is a singular form of "childrens").
Anyway, thank you very much. Context selector looks very nice.

Comment: @tumoxep heheh no problem, `child`  (as in `:first-child`, `:last-child`) is the singular form, `children` is the plural. `:P`

Comment: `children` function selects all descendants, not only first level children as > ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nessia/v6997qzh/)). This works in the example because you don't have nested td.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do `$(variable + " > div")` because `variable` is not a string but a jquery element.

But you can try:

```
variable.children("div");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the cells of the row of index `i`, you may use

```
  var tableBodyCols = $('td', tableRows[i]);
```

If you really may have more than one level of `td`, use

```
  var tableBodyCols = tableRows.eq(i).children('td');
```

or use the native dom object :

```
  var tableBodyCols = tableRows[i].cells;
```

Comment: that first is not strictly a `parent > child` search but a `.find()`.  The third is also now just an array, not a jQuery collection... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* `<td>` cells, use:

```
var tableBodyCols = tableRows.children('td');
```

If you want only those for a *specific* row `i`:

```
var tableBodyCols = tableRows.eq(i).children('td');
```

where `i` will start from zero for the first row.